# Implement the following random generator in PHP

Tags: java, php, scala, random

The following code in Scala and CPP generates an identical sequence of random numbers. I am trying to write the equivalent code in PHP but having some difficulties.

```
class Rand {
    long int seed;

    public:

        Rand(long int _seed) {
            seed = _seed;
        }

        int next(int bits) {
            seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1); 
            return (seed >> (48 - bits));
        }

        int nextInt() {
            return next(32);
        }
};
```

Scala:

```
class Random(initialSeed: Long) {
    var seed: Long = initialSeed

    def setSeed(s: Long): Unit = {
        seed = s
    }

    def next(bits: Int): Int = {
        seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1)

        (seed >>> (48 - bits)).toInt
    }

    def nextInt() = next(32)
}
```

So far in PHP I have the following but it's way off. I think the main difficulty is simulating the 32 bit and 64 bit integers that CPP and Scala/Java are able to do explicitly.

```
<?php
    class Rand {
        protected $rseed;

        function __construct($s) {
            $rseed = $s;
        } 

        public function rnext($bits) {
            $a = ($this->rseed * 0x5DEECE66D + 0xB);
            $b = (1 << 48) - 1;

            $this->rseed = $a & $b;
            // implementation note - in JAVA the next line has >>> not >> which does a zero fill of the shifted
            // value which probably is important and must be simulated in PHP
            $ret = ($this->rseed >> (48 - $bits));

            return $ret;
        }

        public function nextInt() {
            return $this->rnext(32);
        }
    }

    $r = new Rand(916916916);
    echo "rand " . $r->nextInt();
```

Comment: 3 down votes and a close vote in 10 minutes. What is the issue?

Comment: Did you check if your PHP is actually a 64bit version? If not, then `916916916` is not going to work.

Comment: Yes. php > echo PHP_INT_SIZE;
8
php > echo PHP_INT_MAX ;
9223372036854775807

Comment: $bits is never defined, so you're always doing `$this->rseed >> 48`, and your scala code has none of the bitshifting to begin with.

Comment: $bits is an argument to rnext and is set to 32 in the example. The masking in the scala code was accidentally removed and I have restored it.

Comment: ah doh. missed the function parameter.

Comment: I think the first issue is the expression $this->rseed * 0x5DEECE66D returns a value in scientific notation, which when &'d with the 281474976710655 it returns 0

Comment: just how big is this rseed value? If you're generating a value that's >64bit, you'll get scientific notation no matter what you try.

Comment: Php does a silent conversion to double whenever a Int overflows. That makes this stuff difficult.

Comment: Yeah I think that's a fundamental issue. The java/cpp code relies on just overflowing in 64 bit and 32 bit values on the multiply.

Comment: the correct value is 4673227863102408367

Comment: That is outside of a signed 32 bit int? I thought that was was scalas int type was?

Answer (score 1):

I think a library like gmp might be the answer. This is an attempt, not sure if
it's correct and it can probably be cleaned up a bit...

```
class Rand {
    protected $rseed;
    private $mul;
    private $add;

    function __construct($s) {
        $this->rseed = $s;
        $this->mul = gmp_init(0x5DEECE66D);
        $this->add = gmp_init(0xB);
    } 

    public function rnext($bits) {

        $a = gmp_add(gmp_mul(gmp_init($this->rseed), $this->mul), $this->add);
        $aInt = gmp_intval(gmp_mod($a, gmp_init(PHP_INT_MAX)));

        $b = (1 << 48) - 1;

        $this->rseed = $aInt & $b;
        $ret = ($this->rseed >> (48 - $bits));

        return $ret;
    }

    public function nextInt() {
        return $this->rnext(32);
    }
}

$r = new Rand(916916916);
echo "rand " . $r->nextInt();
```

Comment: Looks promising. I need to recompile php with bmp enabled to check it out.

Comment: Yeah, it's a hassle. Also feels wrong when what you want is actually something more low level, but can't think of another way.